# SQLAlchemy + Requests Asynchronous Pattern

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am currently working on an application where a client makes some call to a web services, some small amount of processing is done on the JSON data returned, and then that is stored in a database. I am currently using Requests and SQLAlchemy. The amount of processing is very small (just changing the data to a more relational format). I am not using the ORM for SA. I am just using the engine + transactions.

I was wondering what the a good pattern to do this asynchronously would be (request returned -> handed off to database -> the next request starts without waiting for the DB to finish transaction).

I know that there are a number of tools available in Python (multiprocessing, threads, coroutines, asyncore, etc). However, I am having difficulty finding a good tutorial for my use case.

I was wondering if anyone had suggestions, libraries I should look at, or async patterns that would help me solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: From what I can tell, that's what the database does on its own. SQLAlchemy just keeps a pool of connections open and uses them as you work with the database.

Comment: So no matter how large the transaction is (could be thousands of inserts), the SA will allow the thread to move to the next request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push each request in a [Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) and let a set of worker [threads](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html?highlight=threading#thread-objects) handle each one of them and push them to the DB.

Here is a simple example of the worker body:

```
import threading
import time
from Queue import Queue, Empty
from random import choice

class worker(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.q = Queue()
  def run(self):
    while True:
      try:
        r = self.q.get_nowait()
      except Empty:
        r = None
      if r is None:
        time.sleep(1.0)
        continue
      # do something with 'r'
      print '%s: Handled  request %s' % (self, r)
  def push(self, r):
    self.q.put(r)

workers = [worker() for i in range(5)]
for w in workers:
  w.start()
```

Then distribute the requests to workers like this:

```
choice(workers).push(req)
```

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful. I also want to add that: http://www.nryoung.org/blog/2013/2/28/python-threading/ was a useful article I found this morning.

Comment: That's the most common approach for your use case. Also, consider accepting my answer if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: looks like the link is gone. did it get moved to somewhere else?